# Error on Delivery Message on Spring WebSocket using StompClient

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm trying to send messages to my topic, but the problem is when I send the message nothing happens... I'm using apache tomcat 7.0.53

> UPDATE: 04/15: Link to test:
>
> http://ec2-54-187-72-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/kupo
>
> Login: admin
>
> Password: admin
>
> **LINK TO ACCESS TOMCAT LOG:**
>
> http://ec2-54-187-72-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:28778/
>
> P.S: You need to checked the combobox on the sidebar to start watch the messages

**Github Link: https://github.com/tiarebalbi/kupo**

LOG:

```
DEBUG - gWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Connection established, SockJS session id=_mqg8qer, uri=/kupo/application/807/_mqg8qer/websocket
DEBUG - StompDecoder               - Decoded [Payload byte[0]][Headers=    {stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={heart-beat=[10000,10000], accept-version=[1.1,1.0]},     simpMessageType=CONNECT, id=e79a615e-5522-a0f9-aecf-6ea5a54b3d9b, timestamp=1397013491497}]
DEBUG - StompEncoder               - Encoded STOMP command=CONNECTED headers={user-name=[balbi], heart-beat=[0,0], version=[1.1]}
DEBUG - StompDecoder               - Decoded [Payload byte[0]][Headers={stompCommand=SUBSCRIBE, nativeHeaders={id=[sub-0], destination=[/topic/greetings]}, simpMessageType=SUBSCRIBE, simpSubscriptionId=sub-0, simpDestination=/topic/greetings, id=42c2019d-96a0-95f0-29aa-2bcc62d6d721, timestamp=1397013491501}]
```

CODE:

```
@Service
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent> {

private AtomicBoolean brokerAvailable = new AtomicBoolean();

@Autowired
private MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(BrokerAvailabilityEvent event) {
    this.brokerAvailable.set(event.isBrokerAvailable());
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay=3000)
public void testing() {
    if (this.brokerAvailable.get()) {
        this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "Testing....");
    }
}
```

Javascript Connect:

```
        var socket = new SockJS('/kupo/application'); // <!-- My endpoint
        var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            
            var username = frame.headers['user-name'];
            console.log("User connected: " + username);
            
            stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", function(message) { // <-- Topic where I want to received the message
                console.log("TOPIC:",message);
            });
            
        } , function(error) {
            console.log("STOMP protocol error " + error);
        });
```

**Browser Console:**

```
Opening Web Socket... stomp.min.js:8
Web Socket Opened... stomp.min.js:8
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
user-name:balbi
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

connected to server undefined stomp.min.js:8
User connected: balbi 
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/greetings
```

[image: Browser Console]

**Websocket Context Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketApplicationContext extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    if (env.acceptsProfiles("test.tomcat")) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/application")
                .setHandshakeHandler(
                        new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy()))
                .withSockJS();
    } else {
        registry.addEndpoint("/application").withSockJS();
    }
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
}
```

Comment: do you have logs in your browser console? Can you see a websocket connection in your networking tab?

Comment: Done, i've included the browser console log.

Comment: would it be feasible to post a github link to the code?

Comment: https://github.com/tiarebalbi/kupo

Comment: do you think you could post a minimal example of the problem in github? with the whole application I cannot run it, it tries to connect to a database. also InicializacaoView.js where the code of the problem seems not to be used anywhere in the application

Comment: is this.brokerAvailable.get() true?

Comment: Yes, I did debugging.

Comment: i'm deploying the application on amazon in the few minutes will be available to test.

Comment: Follow the link to access de test application: > http://ec2-54-187-72-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/kupo

 Login: admin 
 
 Password: admin

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to your application, I managed to send a message to a topic from the JavaScript console and get a message back in the web page.

```
var socket = new SockJS('/kupo/application');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.send('/topic/greetings',{},"hello");
```

And I received:

```
<<< MESSAGE
subscription:sub-0
content-length:5
message-id:ts3oov6b-1
destination:/topic/greetings
content-length:5

hello
```

Is your Scheduling task being called as expected?

Why are you, in your main configuration, [importing some Configurations and still scanning the configuration package](https://github.com/tiarebalbi/kupo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tiarebalbi/kupo/configuration/GlobalApplicationContext.java#L31-L32)? Shouldn't it be one or the other?

Comment: Thanks your comment about the configuration profile, i already fixed. Scheduling are working fine. The problem is when i need to send a message from the server to client. I'm creating a link to access the tomcat log.

Comment: https://github.com/tiarebalbi/kupo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tiarebalbi/kupo/service/impl/UsuarioServiceImpl.java#L58-L65

Comment: Follow the link to access de catalina.out from the server: http://ec2-54-187-72-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:28778/

Comment: Enable trace level logging for org.springframework.messaging. You can then trace what happens to the message on the server side.

Comment: to me, "DefaultSubscriptionRegistry - Found 0 subscriptions for destination=/topic/greetings" looks more likely as the culprit.

Comment: DefaultSubscriptionRegistry - Found 1 subscriptions for destination=/topic/greetings
SimpleBrokerMessageHandler - Sending message with destination=/topic/greetings to 1 subscriber(s)
ExecutorSubscribableChannel - [clientOutboundChannel] sending message id=0116c3a3-3167-a540-2420-bc01805b135f
ChannelInterceptorChain - postSend (sent=true) message id 0116c3a3-3167-a540-2420-bc01805b135f

Comment: This log happend when I accessed this URL: http://ec2-54-187-72-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/kupo/test#home with two browser openned. https://github.com/tiarebalbi/kupo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tiarebalbi/kupo/controller/InicializacaoController.java#L45